# Phase two of source file translation?

Tags: c++

I am currently reading this [article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) and I cannot make sense of phase 2.

> Whenever backslash appears at the end of a line (immediately followed
>   by the newline character), both backslash and newline are deleted,
>   combining two physical source lines into one logical source line.

I am aware of the fact that backslashes following by the newline character can appear inside quotes, but phase 2 is explained as if the newline character can be on its own, like

```
int var = 2; \n
```

Especially with part 2:

> If a non-empty source file does not end with a newline character
>   after this step (whether it had no newline originally, or it ended
>   with a backslash), the behavior is undefined (until C++11)a
>   terminating newline character is added (since C++11).

"If the source file does not *end* with a newline character"? Again, it sounds like the newline character could appear outside some sort of string - what do they mean? How can a file ever END with a newline character if this always would be surrounded by quotes?

Comment: source code is plain text and plain text also has newline characters (though most editors don't show them by default), how else would you be able to put code on two different lines?

Comment: The quotes are talking about line breaks in your source files (which are characters too), not about the two characters '\' and 'n' that are used to denote a line break in strings.

Comment: The newline character that the standard talks about is the one that you type in your code editor by using return button.

Comment: Note that the literal `\n` is not a newline. It's an encoding for one.

Comment: @UnholySheep Ahhh now it is starting to make sense. So when I hit enter and start a newline, I implicitly add a newline character in the actual source code?

Comment: @Caninonos How come they then specifically describe it as the characters '\n' ("backslash immediately followed by the newline character") if that not is what's being concerned

Comment: @FacPam Because inserting a line break in your text to mention the character for a line break isn't extremely clear :p Besides '\n' is a single character (single quotes `'`are used for a single character in C and C++, whereas double quotes `"` are used for strings) . And yes, whenever you hit enter, you actually type the line break character(s?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\n` *represents* a newline character when inside of a quoted string literal. `\n` by itself is not a new line character. A new line character is the byte `0x0A` (Line Feed, used by Linux) or `0x0D` (Carriage Return, used by Mac) (refer to an [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table). On Windows, it is the presence of both bytes that signifies a new line character (a Carriage Return followed by a Line Feed, commonly referred to as CRLF).

When you press enter on the keyboard, you insert a new line character into the source code. `\n` is merely what is referred to as an escape sequence. It's a way to represent a character inside a string literal when the character cannot be legally written into the string literal directly.